# Android WebView cache with fragment identifiers

Tags: android, html, backbone.js, android-webview, local-storage

I have several webviews in an app and we've been experiencing some issues with cache.

We have, for example one tab with `http://someurl/` and another tab with `http://someurl/#somehash`

In theory, the cache generated by the first url is the same on the second url, since url changes after the fragment identifier are just page specific.

The problem is, as we call the urls with fragment identifier after the first url is loaded, we still get very high load time. And the worst part is, it seems random.

It takes between 300ms and 2500ms to load the same page. We use local storage and everything possible to make it fast, but it seems that the second page, instead of loading all the resources from the cache, it loads everything again and with this weird speed variation.

Here is how we setup the webview cache:

```
webSettings.setAppCachePath(getContext().getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAppCacheMaxSize(1024 * 1024 * 10);
webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDatabasePath(getContext().getApplicationContext().getDir("database", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath());
```

**So my questions are**:

is there a known limitation with the WebView's caching with fragment identifiers?

Am I doing something wrong in this scenario?

Can the multiple WebViews share the same cache gracefully as expected?

Comment: Do you know for certain all the assets are being re-downloaded (ie. are you seeing requests for these assets on the server)?  Where are you triggering this hash change from, inside the webview (through JS) or from the host app (through an Android SDK api call)?

Comment: Can't say it anymore, unfortunately the project is native now, and I can no longer recall this things. Thanks tho!